# Reflection to find out if property is of option type

Tags: reflection, f#

I am filling some object's fields with data using reflection. As my object is of F# type, it has some `Option` fields. In case of option

```
property.SetValue(object, newValue)
```

reasonably fails, because it needs

```
property.SetValue(object, Some(newValue))
```

Hence, I am trying to find out if a property is of type `Option`. I can do it like this:

```
let isOption (p:PropertyInfo) = p.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("FSharpOption")
```

But there must be some better way, must it not? And I must say it is strange to me that there's no method `IsOption` in `FSharpType`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
let isOption (p:PropertyInfo) = 
    p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
    p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Option<_>>
```

Basically, [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the generic type of the property without any type parameters. And [`typedefof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353533.aspx) does something very similar, only using compile-time type information. In this case, it will return `Option<>`, without any parameters. You can then simply compare them to see if they are the same type.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Could we write `typedefof<Option<_>>` so that to avoid unnecessary `int`?

Comment: I just found out that this solution works great, but only for properties of generic type; for non-generic properties it unfortunately throws InvalidOperationException. We can surely catch it and return false in exception handling branch, but becomes too complex as for me

Comment: @Rustam Sorry, yes, that is an issue. See my updated answer for a better solution.